# Is it possible to assign an Interger signature to a JButton object?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm creating a Dynamic number of buttons and cause of this i cant name each button as i want, also the text inside each button must be empty so i cannot use that too. In the other hand i need to identify each button by an Integer (or even two integers)

in following you have the code of my specific class:

```
    package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import view.Nodes.Node;

public class AdjacencyMatrixWindow {

    public JFrame frame;
    int index;
    LinkedList<Node> nodes;
    int rowNumber=1;
    Iterator<Node> nodeIter;
    JButton btn;

    public AdjacencyMatrixWindow(int index,LinkedList<Node> nodes) {
        this.index=index;
        this.nodes=nodes;
        sortNodes();
        for (Node node : nodes)
            sortConnecteds(node.isConnectedToNodes);
        nodeIter = nodes.iterator();
        initialize();
        apply();
    }


    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 358, 297);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(nodes.size()+1, nodes.size()+1));


    }

    public void insertFirstRowLabels()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=nodes.size();i++)
        {
            if (i==0)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label(" ");
                lbl.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
                frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
            }
            else
            {
                Label lbl = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
                frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
            }
        }
    }

    public void insertRow(Node node)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=nodes.size();i++)
        {
            if (i==0)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label(String.valueOf(rowNumber));
                frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
                rowNumber++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (node.isConnectedToNodes.contains(node.getNodeByID(i)))
                {
                    btn = new JButton("T");
                    frame.getContentPane().add(btn);
                }
                else
                {
                    btn = new JButton(" ");
                    frame.getContentPane().add(btn);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int columnNumbers()
    {
        if (nodeIter.hasNext())
            return Integer.parseInt(nodeIter.next().getNodeID());
        return -1;
    }

    public void apply()
    {
        insertFirstRowLabels();
        for (int i=0;i<=nodes.size()-1;i++)
        {
            insertRow(nodes.get(columnNumbers()-1));
        }
    }

    public void sortNodes()
    {
        Collections.sort(nodes, new Nodes.IDComperator());
    }

    public void sortConnecteds(LinkedList<Node> node)
    {
        Collections.sort(node, new Nodes.IDComperator());
    }

    Runnable selectAndDraw = new Runnable() 
    {
          public void run() 
          {

              btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b) {

                }});

              }
        };
    }
```

sorry the code is not very clean written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the other hand i need to identify each button by an Integer (or even two integers)

You could set the action command for the button:

```
button.setActionCommand("1");
```

The action command is a String that identifies which button is clicked, so it could be a string containing two numbers (you would needs to parse the String to get the two numbers).

Then in the `ActionListener` you access this data from the `ActionEvent`:

```
String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
```

Comment: could you please write me an example ? (how to use this actionCommand in my ActionListener) @camickr

Comment: yea i know how to work with parseInt and String.valueOf... but my problem is that i 've never seen "String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();" so if you dont mind making an example for me or a link to read about it would be perfect

Comment: when i write it as u see in bottom i have nullpointexception

Comment: Runnable changeButtonStatus = new Runnable() 
 {
    public void run() 
    {
     
     btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b) {
      String actionCommand = btn.getActionCommand();
      System.out.println(actionCommand);
    }});

     }
  };

Comment: is the reverse also possible? can i find the specific button by calling its actioncommand? e.g button.ActionCommand(a).disable();

Comment: JButton has a `getActionCommand()` method, so you can loop through all the buttons to find the button with the appropriate action command.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class that inherits the `JButton` Class and include in the class the `Integer` value that you want to store.
I have done this with `JPanels`.  I wanted multiple panels to appear on my window with different information.  So I created my own object that inherits the `JPanel`.
Here's some sample code:

Adding the JPanel (Note: `holdingPanel` is just another `JPanel` on the current Window)...

```
    ScanBarcode scanBarcodePanel = new ScanBarcode();
    scanBarcodePanel.setLabelText(barcodeLabel);
    scanBarcodePanel.setBarcodeText(initialBarcodeText);
    this.holdingPanel.add(scanBarcodePanel);
    this.revalidate();
```

The revalidate is very important for everything to appear after adding the components.
the `setLabelText` and `setBarcodeText` are custom methods inside the `ScanBarcode` class.

The Custom JPanel:

```
public class ScanBarcode extends JPanel {

    public ScanBarcode() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }
...
}
```

Hope that helps.